# d3.js - Customizing line generator

Tags: d3.js

Is a way to change line generator function to add more points than data ?
I need to modify path element generated by `d3.svg.line` to do something like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/marioosh2/ms8f67gq/1/). Now i do it after line is generated like in mentioned example, but have to do in many places. I wonder is possible to make override something in line generator.

```
   var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d,i) { return x(d.x); })
            .y(function(d,i) { return y(d.y); });
```

Comment: You would need your own implementation of a line generator.

Comment: Here is another question asking about custom generators with an example of a custom circle generator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042222/create-custom-a-d3-generator